spotify api for playback return item: none for type episode
I am trying to get the title or id of the podcast im listetning to on spotify.
currently using this endpoint for playback information:
response = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player", headers=headers)
on tracks it returns information about the song and artist under "item"
on podcast episodes this item is always "none".
this is my current code:
def get_current_track():
    if time.time() > globals.token_expiry:
        print("Access token expired, refreshing...")
        refresh_access_token()

    if not globals.access_token:
        print("No valid access token available after refresh.")
        return None, None, None, 0, 0

    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {globals.access_token}"}

    response = requests.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player", headers=headers)

    try:
        response_json = response.json()
        print("JSON Content: -------- ", response_json)
    except ValueError:
        print("No JSON content found in the response.")

    if response.status_code == 200:
        playback_info = response.json()

        if playback_info and playback_info['is_playing']:
            currently_playing_type = playback_info.get('currently_playing_type')
            item = playback_info.get('item')

            if currently_playing_type == 'track' and item:
                track_id = item['id']
                track_name = item['name']
                artist_name = item['artists'][0]['name']
                progress_ms = playback_info['progress_ms']
                duration_ms = item['duration_ms']
                return track_id, track_name, artist_name, progress_ms, duration_ms
            elif currently_playing_type == 'episode':
                if item and 'id' in item:
                    episode_id = item['id']
                else:
                    context = playback_info.get('context')
                    if context and 'uri' in context:
                        context_uri = context['uri']
                        if 'episode' in context_uri:
                            episode_id = context_uri.split(':')[-1]
                        else:
                            print("Context URI does not contain an episode ID.")
                            return None, None, None, 0, 0
                    else:
                        print("No context or item information available for the podcast episode.")
                        return None, None, None, 0, 0

                
                episode_response = requests.get(f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/episodes/{episode_id}", headers=headers)
                if episode_response.status_code == 200:
                    episode_info = episode_response.json()
                    track_name = episode_info['name']
                    artist_name = episode_info['show']['publisher']
                    progress_ms = playback_info['progress_ms']
                    duration_ms = episode_info['duration_ms']
                    return episode_id, track_name, artist_name, progress_ms, duration_ms
                else:
                    print("Failed to get episode information. Response:", episode_response.text)
        else:
            print("No track or episode is currently playing.")
    else:
        print("Failed to get playback information. Response:", response.text)

    return None, None, None, 0, 0

does anyone know any workarounds to this problem?

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python(?) forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Also, do read tag descriptions in general before using any tag. [tag:api] starts with a rather clear message: "DO NOT USE."

Found the solution!
When getting episode information from the playack endpoint use this:
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player?additional_types=episode
